# How to tell libgs to use another freetype implementation?

Tags: linux, printing, shared-library, ghostscript

So after a year of use my printer decided to not print anymore.  After troubleshooting for a bit I noticed that the cups error log shows something like

```
gs: symbol lookup error: <path>/libgs.so.9: undefined symbol: FT_Property_Set
```

I found that very weird.  Since FT_Property_Set is obviously part of the freetype library i checked that:

```
ldd <path>/libgs.so.9
  ..
  libfreetype.so.6 => <path>/freetype-infinality/libfreetype.so.6
  ..
```

and then a grep of `readelf -Ws <path>/freetype-infinality/libfreetype.so.6`
actually showed that it did not define FT_Property_Set.  I also have the
"normal" freetype implementation installed and grepping `readelf -Ws <path>/libfreetype.so.6.14.0` did show that it defined FT_Property_Set.
So after removing the infinality version, libgs used the normal libfreetype.so
and i could continue printing.  My Question is whether I couldve told libgs to somehow only use the normal freetype library without deleting infinality (so that other programs would still use that) ?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to set LD_PRELOAD to original libfreetype.so.
Another one is to recompile infinality with latest libfreetype (2.8.1).