# Error using ps2pdf

Tags: pdf, conversion, postscript

I used to work on linux in a virtual Box and now I'm using a computer with Ubuntu 16.04.
I have some ps files I need to convert to pdf and I used to run the command
`ps2pdf file.ps file.pdf` in my previous computer, but now it doesn't work, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/gs: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgs.so.9: undefined symbol: FT_Property_Set
```

I tried using `convert file.ps file.pdf` and it doesn't work either, I get the error:

```
convert.im6: not authorized `sc1.ps' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/454.
convert.im6: no images defined `sc.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3044.
```

Comment: How did you install the `ps2pdf` utility? It seems like it is missing a library, or has the wrong version of a library.  You can check a little further with `ldd \`which ps2pdf\``

Comment: For the second issue, please refer to this related Q&A: [Error during converting jpg to pdf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081695/error-during-converting-jpg-to-pdf)

Comment: I installed Ghostscript and it turned out to be already installed. The ps2pdf command worked just fine with an example ps file that has only images. However, the files I need contain fonts and I think that's where the problem is.

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387286/how-to-tell-libgs-to-use-another-freetype-implementation ?

Comment: I followed the steps indicated in the duplicate, but the thing is I don't have the libfreetype.so.6.14.0, and I don't have permission to edit the files anyway. I'm working on the last part, but still,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I followed the steps in the duplicate: [How to tell libgs to use another freetype implementation?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387286/how-to-tell-libgs-to-use-another-freetype-implementation)

However, I didn't have the file libfreetype.so.6.14.0 to replace the original file libfreetype.so.6, so I just deleted it (changed its name) and it worked. Don't know why it worked, but it did. Thanks everyone anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Echo Paula's answer, remove or edit libfreetype.so.6. Reason mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57396756/gnuplot-error-undefined-symbol-ft-property-set. I met similar error when I try to open rstudio on ubuntu.

> rstudio: symbol lookup error:
>   /usr/lib/rstudio/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5:
>   undefined symbol: FT_Property_Set

The following codes work for me:

```
cd /usr/local/lib
sudo mv libfreetype.so.6 libfreetype.so.abc
```